Vlookup formula in VBA code changing when macro is run
I am trying to accomplish a macro that will automate the adding of multiple formulas to multiple worksheets where the data range will change on each report.
Currently I have most of it working as I'd like using the following code that loops through all worksheets.
Sub InputFormula()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim excludeSheets As Object 

    ' Create a list of sheets to exclude
    Set excludeSheets = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    excludeSheets.Add "Magic buttons", True ' List of sheets to exclude (add more as needed)
    excludeSheets.Add "Observations", True

    ' Loop through all sheets in the workbook
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        If Not excludeSheets.exists(ws.Name) Then

            ' Insert a new column at column A
            ws.Columns("A:A").Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
          
            ' Apply the formula in A2
            ws.Range("A2").FormulaR1C1 = "=CONCATENATE(RC[1]&RC[2]&RC[3]&RC[4])"

            ' Find the last row with data in column B
            lastRow = ws.Range("B" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

            ' Fill down the formula in column A
            ws.Range("A2:A" & lastRow).FillDown           

            'Auto adjust Column A width.
            ws.Columns("A:A").AutoFit

            'Apply the vlookup formula in Column H

            ws.Range("H2").FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(A2,'Run 1'!A:G,7,FALSE)"     

            'Apply the MATCH formula in column I
            ws.Range("I2").FormulaR1C1 = "=G2=H2"          
        End If
    Next ws
End Sub

The list of problems I'm encountering with this macro are
1 - the vlook up and the match formulas get enter like =vlookup('A2',@run 1!A:(G) and ,=@G=@H.
2 - the vlook up need to change it's target sheet based on the sheet it runs on. E.g if it runs on sheet 1 it'll need to target sheet 2, if it runs on sheet 2 it needs to target sheet 1, if it runs on sheet 3 it needs to target sheet 2. Etc
I'm not sure how to achieve this in VBA
Apologies if this makes no sense I am a novice with VBA and I'm attempting to improve/self teach
I havent tried anything yet as I'm hitting a brick wall,
What I'm expecting is the vlookup formula to function and retrieve the data as expected. With the match formulas to return true, false or #NA

.FormulaR1C1 should be .Formula. You're not using R1C1 notation in "=VLOOKUP(A2,'Run 1'!A:G,7,FALSE)". Same for "=G2=H2".

ws.Range("H2") ? Should that be ws.Range("H2:H" & lastRow) ? same for ws.Range("I2"). change it's target sheet based on the sheet it runs on ? do you mean based on the value of ws.name

ws.Range("H2").Formula = "=VLOOKUP(A2,'" & ws.Previous.Name & "'!A:G,7,FALSE)"  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.previous

Hi @BigBen Ahhhh that makes sense and has worked! thank you :)

Not part of your issue, but =CONCATENATE(RC[1]&RC[2]&RC[3]&RC[4]) seems redundant: either =CONCATENATE(RC[1], RC[2], RC[3], RC[4]) (or, better, =CONCAT(RC[1]:RC[4]), since CONCATENATE is now only present for backwards compatibility, while CONCAT accepts Ranges and Arrays) or =RC[1]&RC[2]&RC[3]&RC[4]; no need to do both!
